# Pass additional Fine Uploader params all the way to the uploadSuccess endpoint?

Tags: fine-uploader

I am trying to pass an additional parameter to an instance of Fine Uploader via

```
  .on('upload', function(event, id, name) {
    var artistId = $('#PhotoArtists').val();
    $(this).fineUploader('setParams', {artist: artistId}, id);
  })
```

with the intention of saving the filename, artist, etc to database in the specified uploadSuccess endpoint.  But I don't think my params are being passed that far in any shape or form.  (I assume they're available in the file I've specified for signature.endpoint.)

Is there a documented way of persisting these params all the way to the end of the process for saving?  Or is there a better plan of action for saving all relevant details to the database at a different point?

Comment: How did you end up doing it? I'm trying to do exactly the same thing, but I am struggling to call the setUploadSuccessParams function...

Comment: @mylescc literally just replaced setParams with setUploadSuccessParams in the .on('upload') function above.  Then I was able to pick up the artist param in the uploadSuccess.endpoint I specified (as $_POST['artist']).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters to your upload success endpoint, you'll need to either set the [`uploadSuccess.params` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-s3.html#uploadSuccess.params) and/or use the [`setUploadSuccessParams` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods-s3.html#setUploadSuccessParams).