# Setting UploadSuccessParams On Fineuploader S3

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I'm making a file uploader whereby a user can select a file, and  then an input appears where they can put in the expiry date of the document and I want to pass this in as part the uploadSuccess Params. I'm using FineUploaderS3.

This question nearly provides the answer but I'm having issues calling the .setUploadSuccessParams method.

I've tried two different methods and neither of them seem to work, but I feel like I'm just screwing up the syntax somewhere.

So one method:

```
callbacks: {
    onUpload: function(id,name){
        this.setUploadSuccessParams({expiryDate: $('#expiryDate').val()},id)
    }
```

Doesn't work.

The other method:

```
$('#submit).on('click',function(){
    element.fineUploaderS3('setUploadSuccessParams',{expiryDate: $('#expiryDate').val()});
}
// Element is the element that I originally called the .fineUploaderS3 function
// I'm calling element.fineUploaderS3('uploadStoredFiles') function that that works
// fine I think I'm just not passing in the variables for setUploadSuccessParams
// Correctly
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciate!

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

This answer comes very close to answering what I want, but just doesn't explain how to call the functions 
[Pass additional Fine Uploader params all the way to the uploadSuccess endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179298/pass-additional-fine-uploader-params-all-the-way-to-the-uploadsuccess-endpoint/22179379#22179379)

Comment: What's the problem you are having? What "doesn't work"? Any log messages? For your first example, you would probably want to use [`onComplete`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#complete), no?

Comment: Is your issue calling jQuery methods? Does [the documentation on the jQuery plugin](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/jquery.html#api-methods) help?

Comment: So my issue is that the params aren't being stored correctly on the document object. After some further research its looking like the second method is working ok except it should be {expiryDate: $('#expiryDate').val(),id: idOfFile}. I'm just asking our Dev in charge of our API if there is an issue his end.

Comment: The docs on jquery methods didn't make it very clear exactly how to call methods that take multiple params which I think was causing me headaches. Thanks for the advice though @MarkFeltner

Comment: You are missing single-quote in your jQuery selector as well.

Comment: The first example should work just fine, and it does after a quick test.  There is some other issue with your code that is not apparent here.

Comment: Yeah, it seems there is a issue with our API. Thanks for all the help and advice!

Comment: You should post your answer for others @mylescc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out my error was in how `setUploadSuccessParams` works. I assumed that it updated the upload success params, but in fact it replaces all the upload success params.

In my code I was initially setting some params (such as a users id in our database), and then later trying to add the expiry date. It turns out I have to set all params at the same time (when I was adding the expiry date).

Thank you for all the help on this one!